# Is that important to useSymfony ACL instead of roles when determining access rights for single objects?

Tags: php, security, symfony, acl, access-control

In symfony2, I have come to a point where I need to create dynamic roles, not only to manage specific general rights, but also gain rights to perform actions on specific objects.

Here comes ACL, shortly described in the doc.
However, I have come to understand that :

1. It lacks the capability to update ACEs when a user changes username : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5787
2. ACL will be moved out from symfony core as it might not be well maintened: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8848

So is that really an issue not to use ACL and instead create a ROLE or a database relationship for every object which access should be filtered ?

Comment: Voters are an intermediate step between simple roles and a full blown ACL system.  Take a look and see if they fit your use case. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html

Comment: yes, I am actually using voters too and that's really nice. But when it comes to storing permissions for objects, isn't it just about saving new roles or using ACL?

Comment: It depends on your use case but if you have specific users needing specific rights to specific objects then you basically have an Access Control List by definition.  Looks like the acl stuff has been moved to it's own repository (security-acl) but is still loaded by default.